# git log for commits matching branch or tag glob

Tags: git, glob, git-log

I want to get a log of all commits matching a branch glob in git.

Consider the following history (lower case letters are commits, upper case commits are BRANCHES pointing there)

```
 /-b --XX, tag2
a--c --XY, tag1
 \-d --ZZ, HEAD
```

I want all commits that match the branch glob `abc*` (in this example none, but there may be some), merged with those that match the tag glob `tag*` (in this example tag1 and tag2). I would expect

```
git log --branches="abc*" --tags="tag*"
```

to return a, b and c, but instead it returns a and d.

Comment: I don't fully undertand your notation. When you say `--branches="abc"`, what is actually in place of, say, "a"? In your first diagram "a" seems to be a commit, so "a" would be a commit hash?

Comment: `git log --tags="tag*"` returns b, c and a. That seems to be as expected?

Comment: I don't know whether any branches match the branch glob, so I can't just omit it. Corrected it to `--branches="abc*"`, where `abc` would be determined by my application.

Comment: For me, `git log --branches="notmatchinganything" --tags="tag*"` matches a, b and c. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: It was in fact a totally different problem: Git automatically adds `/*` to the branches/tags glob if they don't contain a special character, and that threw me off multiple times during these tests. What made debugging worse is that it defaults to `HEAD` whenever the `--tags` and `--branches` arguments do not find anything.

Comment: The issue is resolved, however, I don not really know what to make of this question. Thank you for helping, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to disagree with you. `git log --branches="X*"` does not list the commits pointed to by only `ZZ` or `HEAD`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the described behaviour either. Just get 'c', 'b', and 'a' as expected.

Comment: ah sorry, the problem only occurs if no branch matches the glob, then HEAD is used. That's a problem if I use an additional `--tags=` argument. Edited the question accordingly.